# Alternatives to TextFinder or search for multiple strings

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, filter

I am looking for a way to search for all results that fall between two dates.  I have a simple html page with a text input that serves as a search and currently one date input.  As is, it searches for all results that match the text on the given date, if no text is input, then it searches just for the date and vice versa.  I can't figure out how to filter it between two dates in the same way.  I've tried to get the values and use .filter for all results between those two dates, which works, however the results are not returned in a range array, but instead an array of values (strings).  My code gets the row of each result and arrays other values from that row together.  Therefore, I believe my result needs to be a range not a value.

current code.gs

```
function getValuesFromSS(search) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FormResponse');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();
  var ranges = [];
  if ("name" in search && search.name != "") {
    var ranges = ss.getRange(2, 4, lastRow - 1, 2).createTextFinder(search.name).findAll();
      if (ranges == "") {
        ranges = ss.getRange(2, 8, lastRow - 1, 1).createTextFinder(search.name).findAll();
          if (ranges == "") {
            ranges = ss.getRange(2, 50, lastRow - 1, 1).createTextFinder(search.name).findAll();
            }
        }
  }
if ("date" in search && search.date != "") {
  var dateRanges = ss.getRange(2, 6, lastRow - 1, 1).createTextFinder(search.date).findAll();
  if (ranges.length > 0) {
    ranges = ranges.filter(function(r1) {return dateRanges.some(function(r2) {return r1.getRow() == r2.getRow()})});
    } 
      else if (search.name == null) {
        ranges = dateRanges;
        }
}
```

I've tried this:

```
function filterTest(startdate, enddate) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('FormResponse');
  var lastRow = ss.getLastRow();         
  var dates = ss.getRange(2, 6, lastRow - 1, 1).getDisplayValues();

  dates= dates.filter(function(date) {
    if (date >= startdate && date <= enddate){
      return true;
    }
  });
  return dates;
  Logger.log(dates);
}
```

Which returns an array of values, but does not let me get row numbers of the results.  Here is the rest of my code, if anyone cares:

```
var issues = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Issues</td>';
  var names = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Name</td>';
  var nums = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Emp#</td>';
  var dates = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Date</td>';
  var tnums = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Truck</td>';
  var trnums = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Trailer</td>';
  var urls = '<td style="font-weight:bold;border-bottom:2px solid black;text-align:center">Link</td>';

  //loop through each range
  for (i = 0; i < ranges.length; i++) {

    var row = ranges[i].getRow();
    var lastCol = ss.getLastColumn();
    var values = ss.getRange(row, 1, 1, lastCol).getDisplayValues(); //get all values for the row
    var empname = values[0][3].replace(/["']/g, ""); //column C
    var empnum = values[0][4].replace(/["']/g, "");  //column D
    var date = values[0][5];  //column E
    var tnum = values[0][7].replace(/["']/g, "");
    var trnum = values[0][49].replace(/["']/g, "");
    var url = values[0][66];
    var tkissue = values[0][48].replace(/["']/g, "");
    var trissue = values[0][63].replace(/["']/g, "");
    var mechveri = values[0][67];
    var issue = '';
    if (trissue !== "" || tkissue !==""){
      if (trissue !== "" && tkissue !== ""){
        issue = "<b>Truck:</b> <br>" + tkissue + "<br><br><b>Trailer:</b> <br>" + trissue}
          else if (tkissue !== "") {
            issue = "<b>Truck:</b> <br>" + tkissue}
              else if (trissue !== "") {
                issue = "<b>Trailer:</b> <br>" + trissue}
      if (mechveri == "") {         
        issue += "<br><br><b>Status:</b><br> This issue has not been resolved yet.  Please see a mechanic for further information."}
          else if (mechveri !== "") {
            issue += "<br><br><b>Status:</b><br> This issue has been resolved.  Please see the DVIR for further information."}

    }
    if (trnum == "") {trnum = "N/A"};
    if (issue !== "") {
      issues+=Utilities.formatString("<td><input type='button' value='VIEW' class='issbtn' onclick='alert2(\"" + issue + "\",\"Known Issues:\")'></button></td>");
        }
    else if (issue == "") {
      issues+=Utilities.formatString("<td>None</td>");
        }
    names+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + empname + "</td>");
    nums+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + empnum + "</td>");
    dates+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + date + "</td>");
    tnums+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + tnum + "</td>");
    trnums+=Utilities.formatString("<td>" + trnum + "</td>");
    urls+=Utilities.formatString("<td><a class='button' href='https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=" + url + "' target='_blank'>DVIR</a></td>");
}

return {
  nth: issues,
  first: names,
  second: nums,
  third: dates,
  fourth: tnums,
  fifth: trnums,
  sixth: urls
}
}
```

Basically, it's just setting table information for my html page so I can call it up.
I've also tried regex, but I am not as skilled with it.

Once again, I'm trying convert this to return all results between two dates as input from my html page.  Any help is welcome.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Searching for a String contained in row with first column date between from and to dates**

String in the cell must be an exact match.  It doesn't search from substrings.  In fact all of my testing just involved numbers.

Code.gs:

```
function lauchSearchDialog() {
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('aq5').setWidth(1000);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(userInterface, "Search");
}

function search(sObj) {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('LogSheet');
  var rg=sh.getRange(4,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn());
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var found=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++) {
    for(var j=1;j<vA[i].length;j++) {
      if(vA[i][j]==sObj.string && new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf()>=new Date(sObj.from).valueOf() && new Date(vA[i][0]).valueOf()<=new Date(sObj.to).valueOf()) {
        var ds=Utilities.formatDate(new Date(vA[i][0]), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "E MMM dd,yyyy");
        vA[i].splice(0,1,'Row:' + Number(i+4),ds);//Had to remove Dates() so that it could be returned to the client
        found.push(vA[i]);
      }
  }
  }
  if(found) {
    Logger.log(found);
    return found;
  }
}
```

aq5.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <base target="_top">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {

    });
    function search() {
      var from=String($('#b').val().replace(/-/g,'/'));
      var to=String($('#a').val().replace(/-/g,'/'));
      var searchfor=$('#srchtxt').val();
      console.log('from: %s to: %s searchfor: %s',from,to,searchfor);
      google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(function(fA){
        var html="";
        if(fA.length) {
          fA.forEach(function(r){
            console.log(r.join(','));
            html+=r.join(',')+ '<br />';
          }) 
        }else{
          html="No Results Found";
        }
        $('#results').html(html);
      })
      .search({from:from,to:to,string:searchfor});
    }
    console.log("My Code");
  </script>
  </head>  
  <h1>Search</h1>
  <textarea cols="40" rows="5" id="srchtxt"></textarea><br />
  From: <input type="date" id="b"/><br />
  To: <input type="date" id="a" /><br />
  <input type="button" value="Search" onClick="search();" />
  <div id="results"></div>
</html>
```

Search Sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I am still trying to incorporate it into my script.  I will update once I have progress.